# Encountering One-off Issue Integrating Dropbox SDK?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, foundation, dropbox

I have downloaded the Dropbox API for Objective-C/iOS devices, and I am able to successfully build and run the DBRoulette application.

When I follow the README directions for including the API in my project, I have an enormous number of build errors, all appearing to be related to missing the Foundation header. (Eg. Can't find the interface declaration for NSObject, NSString, etc.)

Many of their header files don't include *any* other headers at all. Don't all .h files need to import Foundation.h if they extend NSObject? This doesn't seem to be the case, as the example project (DBRoulette) builds and runs fine without the Foundation header declarations, but my own application fails miserably.

I must be missing some sort of project setting, but I can't determine what it is.

- [Screenshot of One Failing Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqnKC.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their example app, they have

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

in their prefix header file (DBRoulette_Prefix.pch). This file is automatically prefixed to all source files in the project, so the appropriate headers are found. You can either put the `#import` directives in the source files themselves, or do what they did and edit the .pch file for your project.

Comment: Ah, interesting. The build settings for my target were not using the prefix file. (I already had one defined just as you describe.) The build settings were using ${PREFIX_HEADER}, or something similar (I deleted it before writing it down.) Changing the variable value to "MyProject_Prefix.pch" (the name of my prefix file) fixed the issue. I did some renaming of my project a while back, I'm guessing it was looking for the wrong file.

Comment: @craig Glad you figured it out!